# How to convering list of dictionary to excel

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel sheet below

```
m = '''[{"id":"1","employee_name":"hk","employee_salary":"300000","employee_age":"10","profile_image":""},
{"id":"98021","employee_name":"Maira123","employee_salary":"311475","employee_age":"0","profile_image":""},
{"id":"98022","employee_name":"Arun.G.Kumar","employee_salary":"78687689","employee_age":"28","profile_image":""}]'''
```

My code is below

```
import xlwt
w = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = w.add_sheet('sheet1')
data = eval(m)
columns = list(data[0].keys())
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    for j, col in enumerate(columns):
        ws.write(i, j, row[col])
#columns
w.save(r'C:\Users\Desktop\spreadsheet.csv')
```

My Out

[image]

My Expected out will contain all the  columns which of keys and row as data values

Disclaimer, please dont do in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(eval(s))
df.to_csv('sliced_data.csv')
```

Comment: Check second answer.

Comment: header not available in the code

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `csv.DictWriter`

```
m = [{"id":"1","employee_name":"hk","employee_salary":"300000","employee_age":"10","profile_image":""},
{"id":"98021","employee_name":"Maira123","employee_salary":"311475","employee_age":"0","profile_image":""},
{"id":"98022","employee_name":"Arun.G.Kumar","employee_salary":"78687689","employee_age":"28","profile_image":""}]

with open('spreadsheet.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=m[0])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(m)
```

`spreadsheet.csv`

```
id,employee_name,employee_salary,employee_age,profile_image
1,hk,300000,10,
98021,Maira123,311475,0,
98022,Arun.G.Kumar,78687689,28,
```